# How to define in JSON-schema an object A and object A + field 'id'?

Tags: jsonschema

I am creating an OpenAPI and I want to define an object for the request and another object for the response.

The request object has a list of properties.

The response object has the same properties as the request plus the 'id' property.

For example:

CustomerRequest:

```
{
  "title": "mdl",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "address": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

CustomerResponse:

```
{
  "title": "mdl",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "address": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

The idea is to avoid defining all the properties twice just to add one more.

Is this possible to define in JSON Schema? How is it done?

Comment: Have you seen the composition documentation for JSON Schema? https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand it so don't know how to use them.

Comment: You'll want to use it in combination with `$ref`: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#ref - Any specific parts of the docs you find hard to understand? (So we can improve them). I'll then answer your question =]

Comment: I find it hard to get the schema composition, as the samples are done with simple types (string, number). With examples of objects would be easier to get how powerful they are to combine schemas. Also, I think I got it working with "allOf"

Comment: I agree that the examples should cover your case where two objects share a common set of properties as this is a very common way to think about data modeling when you come from a OO programming point of view. You might find this post helpful: https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/348#issuecomment-322940347